# Need to have custom packages downloaded inside ubuntu minimal iso, how can i do that?

Tags: 20.04, iso

how to (easily?) build a minimal Ubuntu ISO (simple distro I guess), pre-installed with **custom packages and my application**, because sometimes, I have no internet connection during installation of the iso.

Comment: If I had to do it, I'd just read a blog by a *respin* creator, ie. someone who has created a respin of a Ubuntu system which you can download & install, and blogged about how it is done. There are numerous such scripts, but some blogs actually talk about why they use specific scripts (over others) & what changes they made to better suit their ISO you can download (& try).

Comment: That will require a lot of time to set up for something like that, and is only workable for 1 release of Ubuntu; you need to redo it every time. I would stuff those packages on a usb and install them from there. Is a lot simpler and takes only minutes. If you use "ventoy" for installing you can add those packages onto that USB.